# How access to a Class on folder libs in android app?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want use postgresql-9.4-1201.jdbc4.jar in my android proyect (using AndroidStudio). I have adding  the file to folder "libs" that I created, and then I found two problem:

a)In the  "Project" view  I see the folder in "/res" folder but in  "Android" view I see "/res" folder and other folders but not "libs" folder.

b)When I attempt access to a Class of this library when resource R. this name "libs" don't show, and I don't can use it for charge a Driver class that I need.

How I can do that in Android view the folder "libs" is shown? How I can access to class?

[image: comparative]

Thanks you very much.

Comment: you already have SQLite as a driver..no need to load a driver to a different db that is not in android

Comment: I add a picture for for clarify there. How can I access to "libs" resource through R class if "libs" folder doesn't appear there?